# How to display a forum link and user who posted it in my forum?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I would like to display a forum link,  which at right side should also display a user with latest post or thread in a forum.
Apparently here is what I have done.

CODE HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle"></div>
  <h2>INFORMACJE</h2>
  <div class="city">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:81/projekt/forums/forum/ogloszenia-i-nowosci//">ogłoszenia i nowości</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:81/projekt/forums/forum/feedback/">Feedback</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CODE CSS:

```
.toggle {
display:inline-block;
height:48px;
width:48px; 
float: right;
 background:url("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png"); 


}

.toggle.expanded{
background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png");

}

h2 {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(36, 37, 38);
    padding: 11px 10px 11px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here is what I get :(

[image]

Here is how the final results should look.
[image]

How can I achieve that? am newbie please help

check it in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kh3u0q0r/

Comment: what is the relation to php? there is no code to support the question. If you don't have any, then this would either be unclear or too broad. If it isn't related, then the php tag should be removed. There's also no javascript.

Comment: Fred I understand bruh I thought maybe there is a solution using Javascript or PHP that is why I added thank you I will remove them

Comment: Ok, I had to ask. Not my downvote there btw. *cheers*

Comment: Thank u  bruh can you help.?

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you looking for???

```css
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  float: right;
  background: url("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png");
}
.first {
  float: left;
}
.second {
  float: right;
}
.toggle.expanded {
  background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png");
}
h2 {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(36, 37, 38);
  padding: 11px 10px 11px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle"></div>
  <h2>INFORMACJE</h2>

  <div class="city">
    <ul>
      <li class="first"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:81/projekt/forums/forum/ogloszenia-i-nowosci//">ogłoszenia i nowości</a>
      </li>
      <li class="second">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:81/projekt/forums/forum/feedback/">Feedback</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: NO  I want the right side to show user with new thread or post in that specific forum eg FeedBack what you did is just to put the second forum to float right side but that is not what I want, I just want left side forum link  and right side the current user  who posted or created new thread